# Is it right to say "to have the maximum speech perception"?

Tags: word-choice

We have conducted the speech intelligibility test. Is it right to say:

> The test was performed at an intensity level that the individual can easily have the maximum speech perception.

Comment: I suppose it ought to be obvious that "maximum speech perception" occurs at some level *below* shouting, but traditionally that's not how Brits deal with the problem of people not understanding English. We like to pack a megaphone along with the suntan cream when we go abroad for our holidays!

Comment: *The test was conducted at volume levels consistent with maximising intelligibility,* perhaps?

Comment: **level that the individual can easily have** is not good.  It could be replaced with a single word, **enabling**.  *The test was performed at an intensity enabling maximum speech perception.*  And **maximum speech perception** sounds like the jargon of a specific domain, so I won't touch it, though it lacks grace.  And what you mean by **intensity** is not clear. Sound volume?

Comment: Intensity is wrong here, there is no such thing. You don't conduct a speech intelligibility test at an "intensity". Speed of speech flow; and maximum speech perception is wrong, too. In short, the entire thing needs re-wording. I doubt this is about volumes. Speech is intelligible based how fast words are spoken.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say no, due to the fact that it can be less complicated after editing. Assuming you wanted past tense, try: "The test was performed at an intensity level that ensured an individual experienced maximum speech recognition."

Comment: I'll support this answer further by pointing out that speech intelligibility measures the quality of language that is comprehensible

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this is more of a comment because I can only refer to what I know about intelligibility of speech as an interpreter who has to listen to speakers who sometimes go too fast. The rate of the (flow of) speech is too fast.

- a flow of speech is said to be too fast to be intelligible for interpretation. Though it may be intelligible, in and of itself.

The test's rate of speech flow was geared to maximum intelligibility for listeners.

speech intelligibility is a function of how fast a speaker's speaks. It is not a function of "intensity".

That said, there is a maximum limit to what is actually intelligible. And there is a problem with: maximum speech perception. One can perceive speech and it can be unintelligible. Anyway, I think you have to talk about the rate of speech flow. The rate of speech flow can be measured objectively. I don't think you mean speech perception.

I look forward to your comments.